# Js Objects Links for one?

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to make object with different key 'number' with values from arr;

```
var arr = [1,2,4], 
    q = {}, 
    a = { number : null };

for (i=0;i<3;i++) {

       q[i] = a;
       q[i].number = arr[i];
}
```

But with this i got 3 same objects.

I tried to make a closure like

```
var arr = [1,2,4], 
    q = {}, 
    a = { number : null };

for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
       (function(number) {
           q[number] = a;
           q[number].number = arr[number];
       })(i)

}
```

but result is the same. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You already define object `a`. And when you write `a` to `q[i]` it just write pointer to this object. Fixed code:

```
var arr = [1,2,4],
    q = {};

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    q[i] = {};
    q[i].number = arr[i];
}
```

And if cleans up here:

```
var array = [1, 2, 4],
    q = Object.create(null);

array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    $.extend(q[index], {
        number: value
    });
});
```

[.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I ask too easy situation, but i want to extend an object and with this i would got the same

var array = [1, 2, 4],
    q = [], a = { a : 1, b : null}

array.forEach(function(value, index) {
    q[index] = $.extend(a, {b : value})
});

Comment: You must call ```$.extend(q, a, {b: value})```. When you call ```q[index] = $.extend``` you override ```q```variable.

Comment: Why override? q[0] = 'one' , next iteration q[1] = 'two'

Comment: You again create object ```a``` and set pointer to ```a``` not a new object. See my updated answer with extending.

Comment: try to execute your code, it's wrong. q equals empty {};